# path: valid or not in `#include`?

Tags: c, path, include, filenames

Today I read this question [Any rules about underscores in filenames in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684076/any-rules-about-underscores-in-filenames-in-c-c),
and I found it very interesting that the standard seems to not allow what is usually seen in many libraries (I also do it in my personal library this way):

For example, in `opencv` we can see this:

`// File: opencv/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp`

```
#include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"
```

But the standard says:

> **§ 6.10.2 Source file inclusion**
>
> **Semantics**
>
> 5 The implementation shall provide unique mappings for sequences
>   consisting of one or more nondigits or digits (6.4.2.1) followed by a
>   period (`.`) and a single nondigit.  The first character shall not be
>   a digit.  The implementation may ignore distinctions of alphabetical
>   case and restrict the mapping to eight significant characters before
>   the period.

`nondigit` means letters (`A`-`Z` `a`-`z`) and underscore `_`.

It says absolutely nothing about `/` which would imply that it is forbidden to use a path, not to mention dots or hyphens in file names.

To test this first, I wrote a simple program with a source file `test.c` and a header file `_1.2-3~a.hh` in the same directory `tst/`:

`// File: test.c`

```
#include "./..//tst//./_1.2-3~a.hh"

int main(void)
{
    char    a [10]  = "abcdefghi";
    char    b [5]   = "qwert";

    strncpy(b, a, 5 - 1);
    printf("b: \"%c%c%c%c%c\"\n", b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4]);
    /* printed: b: "abcdt" */
    b[5 - 1] = '\0';
    printf("b: \"%c%c%c%c%c\"\n", b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4]);
    /* printed: b: "abcd" */

    return  0;
}
```

`// File: _1.2-3~a.hh`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Which I compiled with this options: `$ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors test.c -o tst` with no complain from the compiler (I have `gcc (Debian 8.2.0-8) 8.2.0`).

- Is it really forbidden to use a relative path in an include?

Comment: It is not forbidden to use `/`, but the result of doing so is implementation-defined.  Almost everything about the sequences between `<` and `>` or between `"` and `"` in a `#include` directive is implementation-defined.  The standard says that if you use a name such as `abcdefgh.h`, the implementation is required to handle it as a unique (subject to case-insensitivity and not using a digit in place of `a`).  The implementation may be case-sensitive; it may allow other characters — these details are implementation-defined, which means that the implementation must _document_ its rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah; the standard is really talking about the minimum character set of the filesystem supporting the C compiler.

Anything in the "" (or <> with some preprocessing first) is parsed as a string according to normal C rules and passed from there to the OS to do whatever it wants with it.

This leads to compiler errors on Windows when the programmer forgets to type `\\` instead of '\' when writing a path into the header files. On modern Windows we can just use '/' and expect it to work but on older Windows or DOS it didn't.

For extra fun, try

```
#include "/dev/tty"
```

Really nice one. It wants you to type C code while compiling.

Comment: However, the standard could have specifically talked about it being a minimum, and that other characters could be implementation defined, but it seems to be very strict about it.

Comment: As I read it, it even says that implementations could restrict it even more but not extend it.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito: Do you read it so because of "The first character may not be a digit?" Unfortuantely, that's just poor writing on the part of the spec writers. The whole thing is setting the minimum allowed, and "shall not be a digit" modifies the previous as in, there's no requirement for a minimally conforming system to allow the first character of a filename to be a digit.

Comment: Yes, that "The first character shall not be a digit" seems to be imposing restrictions. It seems to be banning "1.h" directly, although of course all implementations I know would allow it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd would say it's not forbidden but not recommanded since it will not compile in some of cases there.

For example:

- if you clone this directory into your root (so you'd have `C:\test\`).
- if you try to run it in a virtual environment online, you may face issues.

> Is it really forbidden to use a path in an include?

Not sure what you mean here: relative paths are commonly used, but using absolute path would be foolish.

Comment: Edited.  Of course relative path.  And for the `../` it was just to not have to create a subdir and have there the include, but of course in a real library it would only contain subdirs, and would never go up.